# Oracle, privilege from role doesn't give access to table

Tags: oracle

I need to move some views to a new user(newUser)
The views are to reference tables from the initial schema(originalUser.Table1).

There is a role with 'select' privilege on originalUser.Table1: role1.

If I grant 'role1' to 'newUser' I get ORA-00942 'table or view does not exist' when
*create view newUser.View1 as select * from originalUser.Table1*

But if I grant the privilege directly:
*grant select on originalUser.Table1 to newUser*

everything works fine and view gets created.

What can be wrong with the 'role' approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the documented behaviour; [from the 19c `create view` section](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30__GUID-CD5D4180-5804-4C34-BD78-AEC7549B93A7) (emphasis added):

> The owner of the schema containing the view must have the privileges necessary to either select (`READ` or `SELECT` privilege), insert, update, or delete rows from all the tables or views on which the view is based. **The owner must be granted these privileges directly, rather than through a role.**

Apart from the added complexity that role-granted privileges would add to potentially invalidating a view - if a role was removed from a user, all of the privileges under it, including in chained roles, would have to be evaluated to see if any table access was affected, and then which objects depended on that - roles can be disabled or require passwords etc.

This restriction is similar to the one that disables riles in any named PL/SQL block (procedure, function, package, trigger) created with definer's rights.